# iPhone: 5 seconds video capture

Tags: iphone, ios4, camera, image-capture, time-limiting

I would like to write code so that when the user presses a button, the camera is launched and records 5 seconds of video. In other words I want to have video capture but with a time limit.

Is there something inside the UIImagePickerController or other parts of the framework that would allow doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing that allows you to directly do this. But you can very easily use UIImagePickerController's `startVideoCapture` to begin the capture and then call `stopVideoCapture` 5 seconds later, for example with `[picker performSelector:@selector(stopVideoCapture) withObject:nil afterDelay:5]`.

Or you can do basically the same thing with AVFoundation, in particular AVCaptureMovieFileOutput's `startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:` and `stopRecording` methods.