# PhoneGap/Cordova iOS: capture video with a duration limit (ie. 30 seconds)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova

I would like to limit video capturing to 30 seconds.  As of now the PhoneGap documentation says the following of iOS implementation:

*"The duration parameter is not supported. Recording lengths cannot be limited programmatically."*

I did find this post which seems to give the solution for a purely objective C implementation:

[iPhone: 5 seconds video capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838774/iphone-5-seconds-video-capture)

The question is:  Is this something that could "easily" be made into a phonegap plugin or is there some other reason phonegap hasn't been able to implement this?  If you think it can be done - any information pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: I need the same thing...its ultimately going to be the difference between native and HTML5/PhoneGap. Their documentation (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureVideoOptions) is HILARIOUS too. They show 3 parameters and for iOS NONE of them are supported :s

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying to solve the same problem and may have a solution:

The [capture.captureVideo()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureVideo) function returns an array of [MediaFile](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#MediaFile) objects. Those objects have a [MediaFile.getFormatData()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#MediaFile.getFormatData) method that tells you what the duration of the file is and therefore you could reject the file if its too long...

Here's my solution:

```
 navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFiles) {

                mediaFiles[0].getFormatData(function(data) {

                    if(data.duration > 30) {
                        /* Tell the user the video is too long */
                    } else {
                        /* Video is less than the max duration...all good */
                    }
                });

        }, function(error) { /* An error occured */ },
null);
```

Comment: Any solution to stop the video if the duration is greater than our limit?

Comment: According to the PhoneGap 3.1 docs, only the "limit" parameter is not supported so maybe the duration parameter works now: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureVideoOptions

Comment: This used to work - now the data.duration is always 0